# How do I remove the "medal count" in Yahoo! Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail, ads

For the Rio Olympics, there is a new "medal count" table below the list of folders:

[image]

It bugs me. I want it gone.

Answer (score 1):

Using AdBlock Plus, I removed the offending div **olympics_medal_div**.

Steps:

1. Go to **Filter Preferences > Custom Filters**.
2. Create a new filter group (**Add filter group**) and give it a name, e.g. "Yahoo Mail". Alternatively, use an existing filter group.
3. Create a new filter (**Add filter**) with the **Filter rule** `yahoo.com###olympics_medal_div`. The triple hash defines a **div** on the page.
4. Close the dialog box and reload Yahoo Mail.